# VirtualHost works only if you type the URL fully - my conf is probably wrong

Tags: https, apache2, virtualhost

I'm trying to make my URL link to my self-hosted website for both http and https.
To that end, I wrote a VirtualHost in the apache2 conf file (in sites-available).

It works only partially. Here is the issue I'm having (all of this in Chrome):

1. when I type `www.example.com`, I end up on the Apache2 Debian Default Page, which is located in `/var/www/html`. This is not good.
2. Same, when I type `http://www.example.com`
3. when I type https://www.example.com, then the URL in the browser changes to `www.example.com/index.php/Accueil` which is the expected behavior (it's a media wiki). *However*, the browser returns a 404 Not Found (The requested URL was not found on this server)
4. now for the confusing part : if after step 3, I go to the URL, and hit Enter, then the website appears. The lock icon appears next to the URL, which tells me the connection is secured

This behiavor is all confusing to me, I think there is something wrong with the way I wrote VirtualHost.

Notes :
The website is located in the folder `/var/lib/example`
There is a symbolic link from `/var/www/html/example` to `/var/lib/example`

VirtualHost (`example.com.conf`)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias wwww.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
</VirtualHost>

<Directory  "/var/www/html/example">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3:
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Any sees what I'm missing?
I'm happy to share the actual URL in private message.